# SQL Count Matches

Tags: sql, group-by, count, average, presto

I have a list of 191 values that I want to compare to a column. I ultimately want to get a count of % of rows that have a value in my master list (`matches/(non-matches + NULL)`).

I know I could do something like below but am wondering if this is the most efficient way? Is it possible to create an array that stores the values and check against this? Not sure what the `best practice` way of doing this is given I have 191 values to check against?

I am hoping to avoid dropping 191 csv into the argument since this is a hit to formatting/readability. Is there a way to store these values inside an array or temp table so i can just drop a short hand variable into the actual query? Or is using the below method/average method still the best way to go regardless of how many values there are to check against?

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(field, '') IN (COMMA SEPARATED VALUES) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as matches,
    COUNT(COALESCE(field)) as total_rows
FROM table
```

---

*Also, I believe that `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` are blind to `NULL` fields so can anyone confirm if using `COUNT(COALESCE(FIELD))` ensures the count includes null values from the field?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presto doesn't support temporary tables, but you could improve readability of your query by using an inline table (`WITH` clause combined with `VALUES`) to avoid having a long list of values in the aggregation expression.

Then, you can count the number of matches by doing the following. Note the use of [`FILTER`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#filtering-during-aggregation) for improved readability.

```sql
count(*) FILTER (WHERE field IN (SELECT value FROM data))
```

Here's a complete example:

```sql
WITH data(value) as (VALUES
   'value1',
   'value2',
   ...
)
SELECT
    count(*) AS total_rows,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE field IN (SELECT value FROM data)) AS matches
FROM t
```

Comment: Will this run the `SELECT field FROM data` for each row or will it be executed once? If it queries the cache I suppose it would be just one hit to that query but am wondering if you know?

Comment: It runs once. Internally, it gets executed as a "semi-join". The engine will run the subquery, build a hash set and probe each value in the outer query to see if it's contained in the set.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN field IN (COMMA SEPARATED VALUES) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as match_ratio
FROM table
```

Comment: agh yea - same mistake as last time. The main concern is the 191 values to check against. Is this still the preferred method or is there a more optimal solution? Even for readability since adding 191 values will make this hard to actually follow. Apologies that was not clear - updating

Comment: @urdearboy . . . 191 values in the `in` list should be fine.  It is rather hard to think of another method, unless the values are already in a table.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses `avg()`:

```
select avg(case when field in (<<csv list>>) then 1.0 else 0 end) rows_ratio
from mytable
```

It might be simpler to use an array to pass the values:

```
select avg(case when contains(<< array of values>>, field) then 1.0 else 0 end) rows_ratio
from mytable
```

Comment: errr I phrased my question poorly. This is correct but is not what I was going for. I'm more interested in various ways to handle the 191 values that doesn't involve me manually dropping them into the formula. Essentially wondering if there is a way I can store them in a variable and then drop the variable in the query line instead of 191 comma seprated values

Comment: @urdearboy: well, how you pass the values to the query would depend on the application software that you are using... You might want to show us the relevant part of the application code.